# Python - Ubuntu install for SQLAlchemy not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to setup a ubuntu box so I can do some work, and I'm having a heck of a time trying to get SQLAlchemy installed.

I have tried pretty much everything I can find on tutorials etc, and the latest position I find myself in is:

`easy_install SQLAchemy` seems to work ok, and installs version 0.7.4 (as far as I can tell)

If I go into python and try `import sqlalchemy` I get `no module named sqlalchemy` I also found a script that lists all the modules on the version of python, and its not listed there.

I am brand new to Ubuntu, so I am feeling my way around in the dark a little bit. I'm on Python 2.7 32bit (fresh install) Ubuntu 12.04 (all up to date). Any suggestions?

EDIT: I looked in /usr/bin, and saw that there are three folders that might be relevant - `python`, `python2` and `python2.7` this might be relevant...

Comment: Did you try `sudo easy_install sqlalchemy`? I always put `sudo` before easy_intall usually (otherwise it doesn't work)... But I remember I installed sqlalchemy specifically like @mata suggested.

Comment: I did try that, and probably 4 other ways (all prefixed with sudo) that have probably messed up what `$ python` points too....

Comment: Duplicate question 

["python 3.x no module named sqlalchemy after installation"][1]

Step by step ["walk thru"][2] with commentary

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639939/python-3-x-no-module-named-sqlalchemy-after-installation

[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266188/2255936

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could also use the version directly from the ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install python-sqlalchemy # or python3-sqlalchemy
```

if you used `sudo easy_install`, then the packages usually get installed in `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.X/`. The problem could be that `easy_install` (and also `pip`) doesn't set the file premissions right, so everyting installed is only readable by root.

You can avoid this by using the `--user` option when installing, then the packages are installed in the user site directory (`~/.local/lib/pythonX.X`)

Comment: Thank you, that looked like it successfully installed it, but same `no module` from python. I must have two versions of python installed?

Comment: did you install a second version? what does `which python` say? ubuntu 12.4 comes with python2.7 and python3.2 installed, `python` should start 2.7 and `python3` 3.2

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/python` I installed a fresh version of 2.7 a little while thinking that it might have been an issue with the inbuilt 2.7 version. This would mean that I am installing the module into a version I am not calling? From inside python, `sys.path` tells me its looking at /python2.7 so that explains it?

Comment: yes, that seems to be the problem. you can either remove that version, or try to see that the packages get installed to the correct location (somewhere in `sys.path`), and are accessible.

Comment: OK, I did a complete clean install of Ub 12, and installed slqal as you suggested, and it worked first time. Thank you.