# python 3.x no module named sqlalchemy after installation

Tags: python, mysql, linux, ubuntu, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to install sqlalchemy to interact with mysql database for my python 3.x with ubuntu 12.04, but then when I import the sqlalchemy it says no module named sqlalchemy. This is what i did with installation:

```
aoi@aoi:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy
[sudo] password for aoi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libgio-cil libmono-corlib4.0-cil libmono-system-security4.0-cil libmono-system-xml4.0-  cil libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil cli-common guile-1.8-libs
libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil librhythmbox-core5 mono-runtime libgdu-gtk0  libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 mono-4.0-gac mono-gac
linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic libglib2.0-cil linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libming1 thunderbird-globalmenu libmusicbrainz3-6 libmono-i18n4.0-cil
libmono-security4.0-cil libmono-system4.0-cil
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
 Suggested packages:
 python-sqlalchemy-doc
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
 python3-sqlalchemy
 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
 Need to get 450 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 2,808 kB of additional disk space will be used.
 Get:1 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python3-sqlalchemy all   0.7.4-1ubuntu0.1 [450 kB]
 Fetched 450 kB in 40s (11.0 kB/s)                                                                                                                    
 Selecting previously unselected package python3-sqlalchemy.
 (Reading database ... 346102 files and directories currently installed.)
 Unpacking python3-sqlalchemy (from .../python3-sqlalchemy_0.7.4-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb) ...
 Setting up python3-sqlalchemy (0.7.4-1ubuntu0.1) ...
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What (exactly) did you do after installation (i.e. what did you type)? In fact, are you sure you started Python 3? For me, it "just worked" :-)

Comment: i import the module from sqlalchemy import * then run it by /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 helloworld.py

Comment: Ah... by using `apt-get` you have installed sqlalchemy in the default directory for Ubuntu's default Python, which is 3.2. If you search in the directory /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages you'll probably find the sqlalchemy module. However, this isn't where a custom Python will look for its modules. You'll probably need to download the source and compile it with the correct Python, something like `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 setup.py install` in the source directory for sqlalchemy.

Comment: See the instructions here: http://docs.python.org/3.3/install/

Comment: i checked my /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages it wasnt there either.

Comment: finally working i downloaded the tar file of sql alchemy then run the setup.py using /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 setup.py install inside the directory folder of the sqlalchemy

Comment: My mistake, the install directory is actually, `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Glad you got it working! I'll put this as the answer, can you mark it as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `apt-get` you have installed sqlalchemy in the default directory for Ubuntu's default Python 3, which is 3.2. If you search in the directory `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` you'll find the sqlalchemy module (or just type `locate sqlalchemy`). However, this isn't where a custom Python will look for its modules. You'll need to download the source and compile it with the correct Python, something like `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3 setup.py install` in the source directory for sqlalchemy. See the instructions here: http://docs.python.org/3.3/install

Comment: Yes, but if you type `sudo apt-get install python3`, apt will install Python 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6):

This gets ya sqlalchemy version 0.8.4 for python 2.x
ubuntu is a lot slow in keeping packages up to date

```
sudo apt-get install python3-sqlalchemy
```

So for Python 3 / Ubuntu peeps here is how to install the latest version of sqlalchemy

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
# Now you have pip3

sudo apt-get install python3-all-dev
# Required for sqlalchemy's c extensions to be installed

sudo pip3 install SQLAlchemy
# note using pip, not pip3, will install for Python 2.7

:~$ python3
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> sqlalchemy.__version__
>>> '0.9.8'
>>> print("Who's the man?")
>>> You are baby!
>>> quit()
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was that difficult to find, but it's the one that worked for me. It was definitely about the Ubuntu package, thanks @faulkmore

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `python3-sqlalchemy` is outdated.  You can try to use `pip3` to get the latest version instead.

```
sudo pip3 install sqlalchemy
```

should do the trick.